# when images Scroll then nav Bar updated

Tags: ios, swift4

I have a array of Images and i'm moving images using scroll view and ALL WORKS FINE.
As i'm new in Swift so Now i need a solution for, When the images moving how can i check which image number(or image index number) is showing from total of images and then update Navigation bar accordingly.

Here is attached sample that i'm looking for:

[image]

**code of Moving Images**

```
class ImageScrollViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!

var imageArray = [UIImage]()
override func viewDidLoad() {

    //mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "nature-2")!)
    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "nature")!)
    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "nature4")!)
    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "nature5")!)
    imageArray.append(UIImage(named: "nature6")!)

    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = (self.view.frame.width  * CGFloat(i)) + CGFloat(8)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition , y: 0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width - CGFloat(16), height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        mainScrollView.contentSize.width = mainScrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i+1)
        mainScrollView.addSubview(imageView)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Hope so you guys, understand my Question.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thanks Moritz, I have updated :)

Comment: Better if you use collectionView with pagination -> https://medium.com/@shaibalassiano/tutorial-horizontal-uicollectionview-with-paging-9421b479ee94.

Comment: i can't use this because i have more than 20 to 40 images at once, so using pagination it's look weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `contentOffset` to continuously keep track of the position in `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll`.

So, if the screen is 1000px wide:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    // how far from beginning of scrollView (ex: user scrolls 3300px to the right)
    let scrollDistance = mainScrollView.contentOffset.x

    // size of 1 image (each is 1000px wide + 8px spacing between images)
    let sizeOfOneImage = self.view.frame.width + 8

    // number of images scrolled (3300px scrolled right = ~3.3 images scrolled so far...)
    let numberOfScreensScrolled = scrollDistance / sizeOfOneImage

    // floor(#) turns 3.3 into 3 (removes everything after decimal)
    var imageInteger = floor(numberOfScreensScrolled)       

    // need +1, or else 1st image will be "0", 2nd image will be "1", etc.
    imageInteger = imageInteger + 1

    // # / total
    self.title = "\(imageInteger)/\(imageArray count)"
}
```

Below, `+ self.view.frame.width/2` exists to make the transition to the next number occur when ~50% of the next image is onscreen (can be changed to whatever seems best).

```
class ImageScrollViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

...

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

   let imageInteger = floor((mainScrollView.contentOffset.x + self.view.frame.width/2) / (self.view.frame.width + 8)) + 1

   self.title = "\(imageInteger)/\(imageArray count)"
}
```

Comment: Also please, what is this doing ' (self.view.frame.width + 8)) + 1 '

Comment: you guy is the best, describe it very nicely :)